# Menu to Tap on Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I'm trying to get the following menu to tap on mobile, but can't seem to get it to work. It works on desktop, but I am not sure how to adapt this to have it work when I tap the menu icon on mobile. Not sure if this can be done through css only, or if javascript is required.

```css
/* Body Styles */

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
}

header.dark blockquote {
  color: #fff;
}

header.light blockquote {
  color: #000;
}

blockquote {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-left: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}

blockquote h2 {
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header.dark blockquote a {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header.light blockquote a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header {
  min-height: 450px;
}

header.dark {
  background-color: #444;
}

header.light {
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Navigation Styles */

nav {
  position: relative;
}

header.dark nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

header.light nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.main-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.main-nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.main-nav > li:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

ul.main-nav > li:hover > a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
}

ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
}

ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li {
  padding: 2px 0;
}

ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ic {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 25px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.ic.close {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  top: 8px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}


/* Menu Icons for Devices*/

.ic.menu {
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.ic.menu .line {
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.ic.menu .line-last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.sub-menu-head {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.banners-area {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .sub-menu-head {
    color: orange;
  }
  .ic.menu {
    display: block;
  }
  header.dark .ic.menu .line {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  header.light .ic.menu .line {
    background-color: #000;
  }
  .ic.menu .line {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus .line {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus .line:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .ic.menu:focus .line:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus .line:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(15px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .ic.close {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 21;
    outline: none;
  }
  /*
  
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .ic.close { opacity: 1.0; z-index : 21;  }
  .ic.close:focus { opacity: 0; }
  */
  .ic.menu:focus {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  nav {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  /* Main Menu for Handheld Devices  */
  ul.main-nav {
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 50px 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    /*CSS animation applied : Slide from Right*/
    -webkit-transition-property: background, width;
    -moz-transition-property: background, width;
    -o-transition-property: background, width;
    transition-property: background, width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .main-nav {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  ul.main-nav > * {
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .main-nav > * {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li:first-child {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li > a {
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li a {
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .sub-menu-head {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus ~ ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block {
    border-left: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  .sub-menu-block {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .banners-area {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .banners-area div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .banners-area {
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:769px) {
  .ic.menu {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Main Menu for Desktop Devices  */
  ul.main-nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sub-menu-block {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  /* Sub Menu */
  ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
    /*CSS animation applied for sub menu : Slide from Top */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li:hover > div.sub-menu-block {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block > * {
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li:hover > div.sub-menu-block > * {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .sub-menu-head {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  /* List Separator: Outer Border */
  header.dark ul.main-nav > li > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  }
  header.light ul.main-nav > li > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
  }
  /* List Separator: Inner Border */
  ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 62px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  header.dark ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
    background-color: #777;
  }
  header.light ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
    background-color: #999;
  }
  /* Drop Down/Up Arrow for Mega Menu */
  ul.main-nav > li > a.mega-menu > span {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li > a.mega-menu > span:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    content: '';
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ul.main-nav > li:hover > a.mega-menu span:after {
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #666;
  }
  .banners-area {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Available in two variations: "light" and "dark" | Change <header> class to see impact. -->
<header class="dark">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic menu">
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic close"></a>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a><span>Home</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a class="mega-menu"><span>Products</span></a>
        <div class="sub-menu-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Clothing</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>Mens</a></li>
                <li><a>Womens</a></li>
                <li><a>Kids</a></li>
                <li><a>New Born</a></li>
                <li><a>View All</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Handbags</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>Wallets</a></li>
                <li><a>Athletic bag</a></li>
                <li><a>Backpack</a></li>
                <li><a>Bucket Bag</a></li>
                <li><a>View All</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Shoes</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>Mens</a></li>
                <li><a>Womens</a></li>
                <li><a>Kids</a></li>
                <li><a>View All</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row banners-area">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a><span>Services<span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a class="mega-menu"><span>About</span></a>
        <div class="sub-menu-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Company</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>About</a></li>
                <li><a>Mission</a></li>
                <li><a>Community</a></li>
                <li><a>Team</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Media</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>News</a></li>
                <li><a>Events</a></li>
                <li><a>Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Careers</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>New Opportunities</a></li>
                <li><a>Life @ Company</a></li>
                <li><a>Why Join Us?</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row banners-area">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a><span>Contact</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it with css, if you add:

cursor: pointer;

to the css for your menu button

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I add the cursor to the menu.

Comment: maybe try adding the cursor to the li.top-level-link?

Comment: Doesn't work either, even adding the cursor to the entire body doesnt seem to work.

Comment: hmm, sorry.  i had a similar problem and adding a cursor helped me.  i don't think adding a cursor to the entire body will help.  but maybe if you added a cursor to the mega-menu class?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to be working. Maybe there is a JS solution to this?

Comment: yeah, you could try something like: $( ".top-level-link" ).click(function() {
  $( ".top-level-link" ).focus();
}); or, focus on whatever element would make the menu show...